# Have to mock one internal function and not the other in scala

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I have a function in one of my class for which I have to write unit test for function `generateFeed`.

```
class FeedGen {
    def generateFeed() = {
        writeToLocation1()
        writeToLocation2()
    }
    def writeToLocation1() = {
    }
    def writeToLocation2() = {
    }
}
```

I have to mock `writeToLocation2` function.
So when I call `generateFeed` function from test case, it should call actual implementation of `writeToLocation1` but not writeToLocation2.

Can anyone let me know how to implement this scenario using mockito and scalatest.

Comment: Use a Mockito spy.

Answer (score 1):

So, mocking pieces of a class is generally considered a very bad idea, and smells of bad design (because it violates the Single Responsibility Principle).

The *proper* way to do what you want is to refactor `FeedGen` to extract its dependencies:

```
trait FeedGenWriter { 
   def write(fd: FeedGen)
}

class FeedGen(writer1: FeedGenWriter, writer2: FeedGenWriter) {
   def generateFeed() { 
     writer1.write(this)
     writer2.write(this)
   }
}
```

And then your test would just do something like

```
new FeedGen(new Location1Writer(), mock[FeedGenWriter])
```

Having said that ... if you don't care about software design principles and love cutting corners to quickly get where you want to be, `Mockito` actually provides the tool for you, called `spy`:

```
val fixture = spy[FeedGen]
doNothing().when(fixture).writeToLocation2()
fixture.generateFeed()
verify(fixture).writeToLocation2()
```